# Up-to-date list of Kyōiku kanji?

Tags: kanji

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%8Diku_kanji#First_grade_(80_kanji)), the kyōiku kanji covers 1,006 characters. There's also a reference link to the [Ministry of Education - Japan](http://www.mext.go.jp/a_menu/shotou/new-cs/youryou/syo/koku/001.htm) that seems to confirm this number.

However, I recently picked up [this book](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%B0%8F%E5%AD%A6%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%971026%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AE%E6%AD%A3%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E6%96%B9-%E5%9B%9B%E8%A8%82%E7%89%88-%E6%97%BA%E6%96%87%E7%A4%BE/dp/401011200X/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_ja_JP=%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A&keywords=1026%20kanji&qid=1563356750&s=gateway&sr=8-1) which teaches 1,026 kanji. Upon further research, I found additional books that also teach 1,026 kanji.. [book 1](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E6%AD%A3%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-%E6%AD%A3%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-%E5%B0%8F%E5%AD%A6%E5%85%A8%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%971026-%E5%AD%A6%E7%A0%94%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9/dp/4053047064/ref=pd_sbs_14_2/357-5500241-0213812?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=4053047064&pd_rd_r=aa706d66-a877-11e9-9a4d-29d7ab25ea42&pd_rd_w=EDFHs&pd_rd_wg=yoorn&pf_rd_p=ad2ea29d-ea11-483c-9db2-6b5875bb9b73&pf_rd_r=KF6MJZE8RVG09QFDHMZH&psc=1&refRID=KF6MJZE8RVG09QFDHMZH), [book 2](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%B0%8F%E5%AD%A6%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%971026%E3%81%8C5%E6%99%82%E9%96%93%E3%81%A7%E8%A6%9A%E3%81%88%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E9%9B%86-%E3%81%95%E3%81%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%A8%E5%BC%8F-%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E6%9A%97%E8%A8%98%E6%B3%95%E5%AE%9F%E8%B7%B5%E7%89%88-%E5%9D%82%E6%9C%AC%E4%B8%83%E9%83%8E/dp/4804763066/ref=pd_sbs_14_1/357-5500241-0213812?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=4804763066&pd_rd_r=aa706d66-a877-11e9-9a4d-29d7ab25ea42&pd_rd_w=EDFHs&pd_rd_wg=yoorn&pf_rd_p=ad2ea29d-ea11-483c-9db2-6b5875bb9b73&pf_rd_r=KF6MJZE8RVG09QFDHMZH&psc=1&refRID=KF6MJZE8RVG09QFDHMZH), among others.

The publisher of the book I purchased had an older edition of the book which taught only 1,006 characters.. so I'm curious if the list was officially updated recently, or the authors of these books are using a different version of the list?

> Can anyone link to a reliable source that has un updated list of the
>   kyōiku kanji? Is mext.go.jp the most reliable source?

For those curious, the # of kanji in the book by grade are as follows (with wikipedia #s in parenthesis for comparison):

```
Grade 1:  80 (80)
Grade 2: 160 (160)
Grade 3: 200 (200)
Grade 4: 202 (200)
Grade 5: 193 (185)
Grade 6: 191 (181)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, I thought to add the current state of the list.

4 characters moved from Grade 5 to 4:

賀 群 徳 富

1 character moven from Grade 6 to 4:

城

20 characters added to Grade 4:

茨 媛 岡 潟 岐 熊 香 佐 埼 崎 滋 鹿 縄 井 沖 栃 奈 梨 阪 阜

21 character moved from Grade 4 to 5:

囲 紀 喜 救 型 航 告 殺 士 史 象 賞 貯 停 堂 得 毒 費 粉 脈 歴

2 characters moved from Grade 4 to 6:

胃 腸

9 characters moved from Grade 5 to 6:

恩 券 承 舌 銭 退 敵 俵 預

Totally, 23 taken and 25 added to Grade 4, 13 taken and 21 added to Grade 5,  1 taken and 11 added to Grade 6.

**Original Answer Below:**

You may find the data most easily, I believe, on Kanshudo: https://www.kanshudo.com/collections/kyoiku_kanji . According to them, the expansion will happen in 2020 and involve the addition of the following kanji:
茨媛岡潟 岐熊香佐 埼崎滋鹿 縄井沖栃 奈梨阪阜
I believe, all of these are those used in Japanese prefecture names.

It was not complicated to fint the initial Asahi announcement (https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASJ5K4VGYJ5KUTIL02Q.html) and, besides noting that the names of the prefectures are taught in 4th Grade, it can  only speculate how the yearly designations will shift.

Comment: Thanks, I even came across that website in my Google search, but dismissed it upon seeing 1006 at the top of the page.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like some of those characters are already part of the [Jōyō kanji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jōyō_kanji), so I guess there will be some shuffling of characters..

Comment: It seems some of this shuffling can be found at Kanken, which tests the kanji at different levels: https://www.kanken.or.jp/kanken/outline/data/alterclassofkanji2020.pdf